# List of enums to bit string

Tags: c#, bit

I have created a permission enum Flags that controls access:

```
[Flags]
public enum PermissionEnum
{
    None = 0,
    Read = 1,
    Write = 2,
    Delete = 4,
    All = 7
}
```

If someone requests access the different enum values will be added to a list:

```
List<PermissionEnum> permissions = new List<PermissionEnum> { 1, 4 }
```

How can I flatten out the list of enums to a bit string?
E.g.

```
[1,4] = "101"
```

Comment: Do you really need a bit string? Or is a `int` value good enough? For the later, you can use the bit-wise OR (`|`) operator.

Comment: Note that when doing bitwise operations, it is common practice to represent literal values with hexadecimal. So `0x01` instead of `1`, `0x02` instead of `2`, etc. For the small values you are using, not much changes other than the leading `0x` which signals to other developers that the value should be treated as binary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing it the wrong way. Instead of a list, you should store in a single PermissionEnum variable and for each permission to be added, do a bitwise or:

```
PermissionEnum pe = PermissionEnum.None; //Current value:0

pe |= PermissionEnum.Read;  //Add Read permission. Current value: 1
pe |= PermissionEnum.Delete;//Add Delete permission. Current value: 5
```

Then you can display the value converting the int to a string:

```
string result = Convert.ToString((int)pe, 2); //yields "101"
```

To remove a permission, use bitwise `and` and bitwise `not`

```
pe &= ~PermissionEnum.Read; //Removes Read permission. Current value: 4
```

Also, to check if some permission is setted, use bitwise `and` and check if is greater than 0:

```
bool canRead = (pe & PermissionEnum.Read) > 0;
```

Comment: How would you go the opposite way? E.g. go from bit string to single stored enum

Comment: @Anonymous Do you really need it to be a binary string? Because storing an int or an int as string would be much more easier

Comment: I can convert it to be int instead of binary string if it is easier to work with

Comment: As an int, you could just cast to PermissionEnum like this `pe = (PermissionEnum)7;`

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1**

Combine your list of flags into a single enum value:

```
PermissionEnum combined = permissions.Aggregate(PermissionEnum.None,
                                                (cmb, perm) => cmb | perm);
```

**Step 2**

Convert the combined value into a bit string:

```
string bitString = Convert.ToString((int)combined, 2);
```

Note that if you can change the interface so you just get the combined enum instead of a list, you can avoid step 1 altogether.